# Do I have to add .env file to versioning in react project?

Tags: reactjs, version-control, environment-variables

I have seen some medium blogs and StackOverflow answers that I shouldn't add `.env` file to the versioning.

I quite understand why that is needed.

But how about when dealing with a Reactjs project?

Reactjs is for the frontend and all the environment variables are public even it is bundled for production and anyone can read it using a web browser.

I have 2 env files, `.env.production` for production and `.env.staging` for staging. The environment variable values are put to the bundled version while building. These files are the same across all other team members.

Actually there is no secret at all in these files.

The question is:

**Should I add these 2 files to versioning or do I have to distribute these files manually to other team members? Then why?**

Comment: `.env` shouldn't be checked into your repo *if your repository is public*. The point is that it will expose (what should be) internal information to others. But if you have a private Git repository then there is no issue. Whether your project is frontend or backend doesn't really matter, nor what technologies you use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Preferred way is to have a file called `.env.sample` This will contain all the keys with random or no values in it. Any developer who clones the repo, will get to know the env_vars that are needed to run/build the project.

Within the teams, have a secrets sharing mechanism. There are lots of tools available to solve this.

First time after cloning the repo, the developers needs to run `cp .env.sample .env` and copy the values from the secret manager.

Make sure to add `.env` to `.gitignore` so no-one accidently pushes the `.env` containing secrets to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't. .env file should be put on server in a separated way. Otherwise whoever can access to your source code repository can read or even modify .env file.

Comment: If random people can modify your entire repository then I would say you have bigger problems than a .env files. For a start *your entire application is no longer safe*. With the proper oversight for your repository, which you should implement regardless of files in it, holding a .env is not an issue. At least in terms of modification - yes, you still don't want to expose it publicly.